# How to use contain method for an ArrayList of HashMaps in Java?

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList of HashMaps

```
 ArrayList<HashMap> t = getDatabaseList();
```

and the data inside looks like

```
t=[{taskGroupID=CYQW1634868825, taskGroupName=Fitness, taskGroupColorString=#FFFF3838}, {taskGroupID=ETHC1634868825, taskGroupName=School, taskGroupColorString=#FFFFC107}, {taskGroupID=AAAA1634868825, taskGroupName=Task, taskGroupColorString=#FF00CA38}]
```

I am trying to use the contain method to detect if there is a Hashmap entry-set that contains the key taskGroupName with a value of Fitness. However, I have no idea exactly what to put in the method.

Something like below in pseudocode

```
if(t.contains(key=taskGroupName, val=Fitness)){
   //run code if detected
}
```

I did initialize a new Hashmap variable and set the values exactly to what is found in the arraylist and passed it through the contain method just to test if it turns true and it did pass to true and ran the code when detected

```
ArrayList<HashMap> t = getDatabaseList();
HashMap<String,String> tempVar = new HashMap<>();
                       tempVar.put("taskGroupName", "Fitness");
                       tempVar.put("taskGroupID", "CYQW1634868825");
                       tempVar.put("taskGroupColorString", "#FFFF3838");

if(t.contains(tempVar)){
       //detected to true and ran code
}
```

But if I change say the taskGroupID value of tempVar to one number different, it does not pass to true since it is not exact value and I just want to detect that there is a set with the value of Fitness for taskGroupName without caring about the rest of the values of the other categories cause those might not be the same everytime the ArrayList gets populated.

The other way solution I know at the moment is to run the for loop with the code below but I'm curious as how to achieve it with the contain method instead.

```
for(HashMap<String,Object> hashEntry: t){
         String text = (String) hashEntry.get("taskGroupName");
         if(text.equals("Fitness")){
              //run code if it is Fitness
         }

}
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest you reorganize your data into a defined class.  If you know the names of the fields, then there's no reason to store them in a map.  Just make a TaskGroup class, then you'll have a lot more control.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for ArrayList.contains() and HashMap.equals(). I think you will find that .contains() does not support the kind of operation you are trying to do

Comment: It is a great point that you should be using a proper class instead of a Map, but even using a Map, you should be using a `List<Map<K, V>>` (for some K and V), not an `ArrayList<HashMap>`. Code to the interface, not the implementation.

Comment: Contains is meant to check the type directly stored in the list.  The only ways I could think of doing this would be to create your own class by extending `ArrayList` or `AbstractList` or creating a wrapper class that has an instance of  your `List` and an appropriate contains method.  I would advise doing neither  Imo, your best bet would be an auxiliary contains method that is not part of the List interface.